# When deploying on Heroku, is there a usecase for Parse Server anywhy?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I programmed a web app with AngularJS and Parse and since Parse is retiring, I've started to deploy on Heroku.

In my web app i use Parse as a way to store data (backend as a service). With Parse Server I have to use MongoDB or another database. So I'm wondering why I should use Parse Server when I deploy on Heroku? Is there any usecase combining Heroku and Parse Server?

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to use a Parse Server. You can store your data in MongoDB (or any sql database), and write your own API in Node.js to access and return the data. This code can contain any business logic that is applicable for your service.

However if you choose to use Parse Server, you do not need to write any Node.js code. You can simply use the Parse javascript API on the client side and access all your data through the Parse Server. This can have several advantages:

- You can quickly deploy a client side app without having to write any server side code for accessing your database.
- Parse Server comes with built-in support for handling user logins, Facebook authentication etc.
- Parse Server provides many interesting/useful features that your app might need: e.g. push notifications, live queries, file storage etc.
- The parse client apis provide a significant advantage over using just REST apis for your own server: viz. Support for all major platforms, caching and local storage (for mobile devices), a nice object and query model making it easier to write client code, etc.
- Parse server has an active open source community, so you can expect bugs to be fixed quickly and new features to be added.

Of course with any such platform, there are certain limitations:

- Parse Server is still unproven in high scale production environments. (as of May 2016)
- You have to use MongoDB and the parse data model, rather than using a standard SQL database.
- Any custom business logic that you need your server to execute needs to be done using cloud code. The cloud code only offers limited integration points with queries and may not be the best choice for your custom logic.
- You are giving your clients full access (read/write/update) to the data-model (this can be controlled some what using ACLs). This makes building custom end-points difficult.

My conclusion is Parse Server is great to use if you want to quickly get an application up and running e.g. for a demo or for testing. However you should carefully evaluate the limitations if you want to use it in production.